# .split("|") doesn't return the correct string

Tags: java

I'm sending this string from the client to the server:

```
Ar|0.04107356|-0.31299785|-0.9991561
```

That string is as printed out by the server - So it is correct.

"Ar" is the packet name, and the values are the velocity of an arrow that the archer is going to shoot.

So to get those values, I'm using

```
String[] values = str.split("|");
```

And then

```
a.shoot(Float.valueOf(values[1]), Float.valueOf(values[2]), Float.valueOf(values[3])); //a is an archer
```

The problem is, values[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrkIk.png), values[2], and values[3] seem to be corrupt or unrecognizable.

My full code is this:

```
 public void handleMessage(String str){
    System.out.println(str);
    String[] values = str.split("|");
    if (values[0].contains("Ar")){
        System.out.println("X: " + values[1] + " Y: " + values[2] + " Z: " + values[3]);
    }
    System.out.println("Vals: " + values[0] + " " + values[1] + " " + values[2] + " " + values[3]);
    if (true) return; //Returning so I can analyze de-bug messages without crashes.
    for (Archer a : GameServer.archers){
        a.shoot(Float.valueOf(values[1]), Float.valueOf(values[2]), Float.valueOf(values[3]));
    }
```

When I print out the "Vals" message, it comes out like this:

```
Vals:  A r |
```

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What IDE are you using that it does not warn you about REGEX?

Comment: A lot of IDE don't warn you, but one should be well versed in documentation.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The horizontal bar has a special meaning in Java regular expressions which you must escape in order to use as a literal:

```
String[] values = str.split("\\|");
```

Comment: Would you mind marking as answer?